# how to add class to div in which radio has certain value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form with 4 radios:

```
<form class="options" method="post" id="question" action="index.php">
    <div class="form-check form-group"> 
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class='radio form-check-input' type='radio' name='radio' value='1' />Radio 1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-group"> 
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class='radio form-check-input' type='radio' name='radio' value='2' />Radio 2
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-group"> 
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class='radio form-check-input' type='radio' name='radio' value='3' />Radio 3
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-group"> 
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class='radio form-check-input' type='radio' name='radio' value='4' />Radio 4
        </label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="next" value="next">NEXT</button>

</form
```

How can i add a class `alert-success` to the div above in which the radio has value 2 (with jquery)?

So:

```
 <div class="form-check form-group alert-success"> 
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class='radio form-check-input' type='radio' name='radio' value='2' />Radio 2
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:has` jQuery selector:

```
$('.form-group:has(input[value=2])').addClass('alert-success');
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('input[value=2]').closest('div').addClass('alert-success');`

Also works..

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').filter('[value=2]').closest('.form-group').addClass('alert-success');
```